# How to recover a gzipped folder e.g. folder.gz which was zipped as a 'file'

Tags: compression, gzip

I have a folder which I compressed using:

```
gzip -c filename > filename.gz
```

I know this is wrong as I was supposed to use:

```
gzip -r directory
```

I now have a compressed folder which my system thinks is a file. When I try to unzip it using:

```
gzip -dr directory
```

it just uncompresses as a file when it should be a directory.

Have I just corrupted this folder or is there any way to recover this data? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should have said "gzip: filename is a directory -- ignored", and filename.gz would be an empty file.

Comment: @Mark Adler Thanks for your reply. I think I've been trying to decompress using the gzip command instead of gunzip.

Comment: The gzip command will decompress with the `-d` option. gunzip is in fact that same executable, where `-d` is implied by the executable name.